# How to specify a nullable value on create function in modal in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

In a model, how are we able to insert a nullable validated field with the create function? For example, in the RegisterController: the basic validator + the create function. If I didn't send the `google_id` or `facebook_id,` the create function returns an undefined index (obviously) on the fields. What's the proper way to insert them?

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['nullable', 'email', 'unique:users'],
        'google_id' => ['nullable', 'string', 'unique:users'],
        'facebook_id' => ['nullable', 'string', 'unique:users'],
        'twitter_id' => ['nullable', 'string', 'unique:users'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:10', 'min:10', 'unique:users', "regex:/(^[1-9][0-9]*$)/"],
        'country_code' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'exists:'.config('countries.table_name').',calling_code'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'phone' => $data['country_code'].$data['phone'],
        'google_id' => $data['google_id'] ? $data['google_id'] : null,
        'facebook_id' => $data['facebook_id'] ? $data['facebook_id'] : null,
        'twitter_id' => $data['twitter_id'] ? $data['twitter_id'] : null,
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I know it's a fundamental question, and I do know how to ignore them, but I need to know what the correct format is.

Comment: The latest one . Laravel 6

Comment: Oh, my bad. I will update

Comment: no worries, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the new format available in php 7

```php
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['country_code'].$data['phone'],
            'google_id' => $data['google_id']??null,
            'facebook_id' => $data['facebook_id']??null,
            'twitter_id' => $data['twitter_id']??null,
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: I know about this.  There should be some other way where laravel handles this, isn't it? like verify the same before inserting? I am not sure if what I am saying is correct though..

Comment: @VishnuRaj some other way where laravel handles what?

Comment: @lagbox I meant while creating returning the data from validator, doesn't Laravel append this so said nullable value? Even if it is Null?

Comment: @VishnuRaj your error has nothing to do with the creation of a record .. you are referencing an array index that doesn't exist ... it is PHP not Laravel

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `collect` here:

```
$data = collect($data);
```

You can call the `->get` method, which if the index is not found will return `null` by default.

```
$data->get('facebook_id');
```

Alternatively, you can use `data_get` as well, which is another nifty Laravel helper and allows you to avoid mutating the array its self.

```
data_get($data, 'facebook_id', null)
```

Finally, you can use `->only()` if your database was setup with the value being `nullable()` in the schema:

```
User::create(collect($data)->only([...fields]));
```

This requires setting the appropriate `fillable` properties on the model as well:

```
protected $fillable = [...fields];
```

Comment: That's also a good point. But is there any other way, that laravel handles it automatically?

Comment: @VishnuRaj for laravel to handle what automatically?